# Persist login in sales force while offline in IOS

Tags: ios, salesforce, offline

I want to make my app logged in while in offline mode but i unable to find any documentation for this please guide me. i am using the native rest template

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep user logged in even if app is in background ?

Comment: i want user logged in when there is no network available

Comment: @RahulNagpal Can you give brief explanation about your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't be logged into Salesforce when the app is offline, as you can't authenticate with Salesforce. It sounds like you need to implement your own PIN or password system that works locally.

As @superfell says, you need to accept more answers if you're looking to get good answers.